# Command line or PowerShell to manage Windows backup history

Tags: backup, windows-10

I'm backing up my Windows 10 machine using the Windows 7 classic backup feature so I can get a full system image. As part of it I'm getting a growing number of backup periods see image below. It keeps filling the disk and I can't see any way to remove these, I had seen someone mention using this command `wbadmin delete backup -keepversions:7 -quiet` but it tells me I only have one backup, is there another command line I can script to keep on top of this so it doesn't keep growing to fill the disk?

[image]

I have this ticked already but it still filled the drive to 3mb remaining.

[image]